# The protocol method of GKAgentDelegate is not right in Swift?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, ios9, gameplay-kit

In GameplayKit, I want to conform the protocol GKAgentDelegate, hence use the delegate method `func agentDidUpdate(agent: GKAgent)`.

The problem is, in this method, the parameter agent is declared as GKAgent, not GKAgent2D, so that I cannot access `agent.position`, because the position property is in GKAgent2D, not GKAgent...

However in Objective-C API, agent is declared as GKAgent2D.

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `GKAgent2D` is a subclass of `GKAgent`, you can simply *upcast* it:

```
func agentDidUpdate(agent: GKAgent) {
    if let agent2d = agent as? GKAgent2D {
        // do thing with agent2d.position
    }
}
```

The documentation for `GKAgentDelegate` (from Xcode 7, beta 1; i.e. the OSX 10.11 SDK) shows the same type (`GKAgent`) for both languages:

[image]

So it should have always been `GKAgent` under Objective-C in order to be strictly correct, however Objective-C is less type-safe than Swift, so you could get away with it (with the possibility that you'd get an `unrecognized selector` exception if a `GKAgent` object was ever passed to the delegate method and you assumed it was a `GKAgent2D`).

Comment: This works, thank you. But I still do not understand why they declare agent as GKAgent in Swift, but GKAgent2D in Objective-C..

Comment: Oh yeah, it is both `GKAgent`, my bad. The demo code just change it to `- (void)agentDidUpdate:(nonnull GKAgent2D *)agent` when implementing.